# PHP Session working but hidden in Chrome Resources tab

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

I have an odd problem with PHP Sessions (using php 5.6) both in localhost and own webhost.

I create a new session, I echo it and it gets displayed. However when I head to Resources -> Cookies -> localhost/mydomain.com I only see PHPSESSID, and not the session I created.

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = "test";

echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

Picture right after I run the code above:

[image]

What is wrong with what I do? Or is it a PHP or Chrome related issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP Sessions are server-side. It's not an issue, it's by design.

On the client side, meaning chrome or any other browser, there is only the session id. That's what is stored as "PHPSESSID"-Cookie if not modified. Everything else stays on the server. You can't access this from chome.

To see the session-data, you can create a php site with this content:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Edit: This simple example only works if you don't save class instances inside your $_SESSION. In this case the classes must be defined before session_start().

Comment: Hell, I believe I was confusing sessions with cookies. The cookies do appear there, but the sessions don't, which makes perfect sense. Thanks for the quick response!